# e.preventDefault() not working as expected with TAB key and "onchange" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

On a input field I has a "change" event, this event dispatch a ajax request and if return error, this error is injected on html on top of page.
But if I press key "TAB" the cursor auto focus on next input field, like TAB event is dispatched before "change" event, screen don't roll to top of page on error message.

Is there any way to deal with that? Or am I using "change" on wrong way, maybe better use "keydown" instead?

```js
function myLogicFunction() {
    console.log('execute ajax call with some logic');
}

$('#name').change(function(e){
    myLogicFunction()
});

$('#name').keydown(function(e){
  if(e.key === 'Tab') {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).trigger('change');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name: <input type="text" id="name" />
<br>
Bio: <textarea cols="60" rows="5" id="bio"></textarea>
```

I did this, handle "TAB" key, but de problem now is: after run this listener when I click anywhere of page "onchange" event is dispatched. I think this is normal behavior because the field value changed. But how I prevent this behavior? My function "myLogicFunction" was already called e that way will be called again.

Comment: It works as expected for me. When I press TAB it stays in the input field.

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log(e.key)` to see if why it doesn't match?

Comment: The browser might be doing it because of `keyup` event.

Comment: The `change` event occurs whenever you edit an input and then leave it. Why shouldn't it happen when you click somewhere else?

Comment: Also don't override standard accessibilty keys

Comment: @Yogi in my function "myLogicFunction" there a ajax call, on "error" function I handle exception message injecting it inside a div located on top of page and scroll screen for there. When Tab key is clicked, by default, cursor goes to next input making screen don't scroll to top.

Comment: @Barmar as shown in console, you can see "myLogicFunction" called twice. I need that as "onchange" listener be called only one time when key TAB is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *blur* event, you can also try to remove *change()* event.
I also suggest to keep the logic in *myLogicFunction()* so every event calls that, instead of doing chaining calls

**Update:** *adapted the answer with the last informations provided*:

We save the last value of the tested input to know if it's value has changed

```js
let oldNameVal = "";

function myLogicFunction() {
    console.log('execute ajax call with some logic');
}

$('#name').blur (function(e){

    const testVal = oldNameVal;
    oldNameVal = this.value;

    if (this.value !== testVal)
       myLogicFunction()

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name: <input type="text" id="name" />
<br>
Bio: <textarea cols="60" rows="5" id="bio"></textarea>
```

Comment: Whenever the input field loose focus "myLogicFunction" will be called. I want that function "myLogicFunction" would be called only if input value change.

Comment: @KauanMocelin I've modified my answer to achieve your requirements

Comment: Good anwser @Pippo. For learning purposes, why in my original code when call "$(this).trigger('change');" that event is called twice(when clicked somewhere) and with default behaviour of key tab don't? I can't understand what e.preventDefault is preventing in this case.

Comment: @KauanMocelin, it was triggered twice because the first is called by your *trigger()* instruction and the second by the natural event *change()* : to mange this situation you would have had to set some variable as semaphore I think.
The *preventdefault()* prevented the TAB key normal execution: the TAB key did not move to the next control